# Can't checkout in subversion

Tags: svn

I tried to checkout a repository in subversion and it says

```
svn: Can't open file 'eglibc2.8/ports/sysdeps/m88k/m88100/.svn/tmp/text-base/add_n.s.svn-base': No such file or directory
```

I checked and there really is not such file.
What is making it do this? I cannot control the svn repository, I just need to checkout a library.
I'm on a mac so it can't be case sensitivity problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it may still be a problem of case sensitivity. Although Mac OS X distinguishes between cases, two files with names that only differ in the case are considered to be the same.

Looking at http://www.eglibc.org/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/trunk/ports/sysdeps/m88k/m88100/ this seems to be the case: there are two files `add_n.s` and `add_n.S`, which are the cause of your problem.
Sorry, I have no idea what to do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something crazy like making a sparse disk image that was formatted to be case sensitive and then checkout/work with the repo there.  Not a system you'd want to use often, but if it's just this once...